# javascript - create new (global) objects with names from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to create new Objects with names out of an array.
Without an array i would do:

```
var object_bruno = new Object();
var object_carlos = new Object();
var object_luci = new Object();
```

so i will end up with 3 new Objects. But why wont we do that with an loop, which makes it more easy to adde some more Objects later. So i ttried:

```
//      an array full of object names
var obj_arr = [ "object_bruno", "object_carlos", "object_luci"];

//      Method one:
for (x in obj_arr) {
    alert(obj_arr[x]);      //  right names shown
    var obj_arr[x] = new Object();  //syntax error, dosent work??
};

//      Method two:
obj_arr.forEach(function(func_name) {
    alert(func_name);       //  right names
    var func_name = new Object();   //  no objects are created ???
});
```

basicly i would prefer to use Method two. i like it because i can fill them late the same way? hopefuly? Any ideas what wents wrong?

Comment: Please add your code in fiddle .. That is very helpful for people to understand your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/krL4fxuL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop over the array and assign a `new Object` to each of the items , like this:

```
for (var i = 0, l = obj_arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj_arr[i] = {};
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also do it in this way by applying properties to the `global` object, for example `window`:

```
var people = [ "object_bruno", "object_carlos", "object_luci"];

for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    global[people[i]] = {};
}
```

Using this solution makes the objects global, so you can use them like `object_bruno`.

Another *improvement* can be the usage of [`computed propertiey names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) of ECMAScript 2015:

```
var people = [ "bruno", "carlos", "luci"], prefix = 'object_';

for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    global[prefix + people[i]] = {};
}
```

This allows to have more *meaningful* array.

Note, the `global` can be the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object in browsers or [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object in NodeJS, or perhaps something else in other environments.

Comment: Thanks for Your quick answer! Your code lead into "ReferenceError: object_bruno is not defined" i tried as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/krL4fxuL/

Comment: Try the updated solution, with `global` replaced with `window`.

Comment: your are allready close!!: "" ReferenceError: global is not defined "" when using global

Comment: I've provided the fiddle above, also I have a note in the solution at the end. Please read it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a new variable by declaring

```
obj_arr.forEach(function(func_name) {
    alert(func_name);       //  right names
    var func_name = new Object();   //  no objects are created ???
});
```

try this

```
obj_arr.forEach(function(func_name) {
        alert(func_name);       //  right names
        func_name = new Object();   //  no objects are created ???
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj_arr = [ "object_bruno", "object_carlos", "object_luci"];

obj_arr.forEach(function(func_name, index, arr) { 
    arr[index] = {}; 
});
```